# Angular http return Mat Table filter data to specific columns

Tags: angular

I want to filter the api return based specific column in mat-table. In my case , I want the the table only show finished status only. right now I manage to display the data on the mat table

here is my component.ts

```
export class EarningComponent implements OnInit {
  bookings: any = [];
  jobs:any = [];
  product:any =[];
  filterbooking:any =[];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id','title','status','painter_name','earning'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getlist()
  }

  getlist() {
    const body = {
      opcode: 'order_list',
      size: 20,
      page: 1,
      sign: 'e5111c807c49a330399b4ca36a27162',
    };
    this.http
      .post<any>('http://api.1shikj.com/cgi-bin/operate', body)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.bookings = data.data.data;
      });
  }
}
```

here is my output
[image]

Comment: if you want to make displayed columns more dynamic or even change the data (ie. change columns), you could store data in a BehaviourSubject and use rxjs methods like combineLatest or withLatestFrom()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the array being returned from you http request, then you can apply the `.filter()` method to that array.

```
this.bookings = data.data.data.filter(booking=>booking.status==='finished');
```